# Malformed matrix while using hstack?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have the following matrices:

```
>>> X1
shape: (2399, 39999)
type: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

And

```
>> X2
shape: (2399, 333534)
type: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
```

And

```
>>>X3.reshape(-1,1)
shape: (2399, 1)
type: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

How can I concatenate X1 and X2 by the right side in order to generate a new matrix with the following shape: `(2399, 373534)`. I know that this can be done with scipy's [hstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html#scipy.sparse.hstack) or [vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.vstack.html). However, when I tried to:

```
X_combined = sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.T])
```

However, I got a malformed final matrix:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Therefore, how can I concatenate correctly in a single matrix?.

**UPDATE**

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=5)
X1 = count_vect.fit_transform(X)
```

And

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tdidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
X2 = tdidf_vect.fit_transform(X)
```

And

```
from hdbscan import HDBSCAN
clusterer = HDBSCAN().fit(X1)
X3 = clusterer.labels_
print(X3.shape)
print(type(X3))
```

Then:

In:

```
import scipy as sparse

X_combined = sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.reshape(-1,1)])
```

Out:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-14baa47e0993> in <module>()
      5 
      6 
----> 7 X_combined = sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.reshape(-1,1)])

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    284     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    285     if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 286         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    287     else:
    288         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: `scipy.sparse.hstack` needs sparse input. Also, `X3` is not implicitly treated as a column.

Comment: I also tried to do X3.reshape(-1,1) and still is malformed when I concatenate them. Any idea of what can I do?. @user2357112

Comment: Please provide a self-contained example so we can replicate your issue.

Comment: How can I give you this example?... I provided you with the shape of each matrix @Kochoba

Comment: @tumbleweed Why are you transposing x3? to use hstack your arrays must agree on the first dimension and they already do.

Comment: I know it. I just do not know what else I can do in order to hstack them. These are the dimentions of my matrices: X1: (2399, 39351), scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix, X2: (2399, 256611) scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix, and X3: (2399,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: @tumbleweed I can not replicate your issue. Without the transpose hstack works just fine for me

Comment: The weird thing is when I hstack only X1 and X2 matrices: `(2,)
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:295: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Comparing sparse matrices using >= and <= is inefficient, using <, >, or !=, instead.
  "using <, >, or !=, instead.", SparseEfficiencyWarning)
Out[24]:
array([ <2399x39351 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
 with 1237261 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
       <2399x39351 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
 with 1237261 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>], dtype=object)`

Comment: @Kochoba I updated with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your import, it should be

```
from scipy import sparse
```

The top-level `scipy` module (normally you shouldn't use the top-level scipy module anyway) imports the numpy functions, so when you try your version:

```
>>> import scipy as sparse
>>> sparse.hstack
<function numpy.core.shape_base.hstack>

>>> # incorrect! Correct would be

>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> sparse.hstack
<function scipy.sparse.construct.hstack>
```

This is all mentioned in their [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html#guidelines-for-importing-functions-from-scipy):

> The scipy namespace itself only contains functions imported from numpy. These functions still exist for backwards compatibility, but should be imported from numpy directly.
>
> Everything in the namespaces of scipy submodules is public. In general, it is recommended to import functions from submodule namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

Why the `X3.T`?  `X3.reshape(-1,1)` shape is compatible with the others

```
sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.reshape(-1,1)])
```

should work.

```
[(2399, 39999), (2399, 333534), (2399, 1)]
```

The use of `sparse.hstack` is correct here; but the the same rules about matching dimensions applies, whether sparse or dense.

```
In [207]: M
Out[207]: 
<10x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 9 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [208]: sparse.hstack((M,M))
Out[208]: 
<10x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 18 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

`sparse.hstack` will convert `A` to sparse before doing its version of concatenate.

```
In [209]: A=np.ones((10,1),int)
In [210]: sparse.hstack((M,M,A))
Out[210]: 
<10x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 28 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

or you could convert it to sparse first.

```
In [211]: As=sparse.csr_matrix(A)
In [212]: As
Out[212]: 
<10x1 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
In [213]: sparse.hstack((M,M,As))
Out[213]: 
<10x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 28 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Starting with a 1d `A`:

```
In [214]: A=np.ones((10),int)
In [215]: sparse.hstack([M,M,A.reshape(-1,1)])
Out[215]: 
<10x7 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 28 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I am still facing this issue: `sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.reshape(-1,1)])`, then: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: `same number of dimensions` - tell us again, what are the dimensions of those 3 inputs.  For `sparse` they must all have 2 dimensions.

Comment: This are the types and the shapes: `X1: (2399, 39351), scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, `X2: (2399, 256611) scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`, and X3: `(2399,) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>`.

Comment: Note that I removed the `reshape`. Those are the raw shapes.

Comment: Who exactly is issuing that `ValueError`?  I.e. what's the error stack?

Comment: `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-0d15d43fbb2f> in <module>()
      5 
----> 7 X_combined = sparse.hstack([X1,X2,X3.reshape(-1,1)])
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    284     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    285     if arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 286         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    287     else:
    288         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: That error is coming from `np.hstack`, not `sparse.hstack`.  Something has replaced one with the other, either on the file or after import.  `sparse.hstack` does not use the `numpy` version.